# MobX autorun not working class component constructor

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

React is actually unbelievably hard T_T....

I just want to **invoke a component method** when there's a state change. I can do this easily with a watcher in Vue. But what am I supposed to do in React class component and MobX's autorun? Would this work in a functional component instead?

```
import someStore 

@observer
class MyComponent {
    constructor(){
       autorun( 
         // references someStore.someObservable
         // call component methods 
         // but this isn't hit when there's change
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made 2 examples for you, one with class component which is not recommended way to do things anymore, and one with functional component.

Example is quite escalated, because it would be much easier to compute our `status` in render, but let's pretend we can't do that and we want to invoke some internal method.

First, we setup out store and update it every second:

```
import { observable, reaction } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const store = observable({
  counter: 0
});

setInterval(() => {
  store.counter++;
}, 1000);

// Helper method
const getStatus = (number) => (number % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
```

Here is our functional component, we use `useEffect` to react to counter changes and then update our internal state with `setStatus` method:

```
const CounterFunctional = observer(() => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(() => getStatus(store.counter));

  useEffect(() => {
    setStatus(getStatus(store.counter));
  }, [store.counter]);

  return <div>functional: {status}</div>;
});
```

Here is our class component, now we use MobX `reaction` (don't forget to dispose it on unmount) and similarly update our internal state after `counter` changes:

```
const CounterClass = observer(
  class extends React.Component {
    disposer;

    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
        status: getStatus(store.counter)
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.disposer = reaction(
        () => store.counter,
        () => {
          this.setState({
            status: getStatus(store.counter)
          });
        }
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.disposer();
    }

    render() {
      return <div>class: {this.state.status}</div>;
    }
  }
);
```

Hope it makes sense, React is actually super easy library :)

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions66602050-7uhm6

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! The functional one is an interesting example to me. I did however try to use autorun in both constructor and the mount hook and it works now. Maybe it's due to cacheing. 
Though these hooks docs are pretty daunting to read with all the gotchas. I wanna ask about the use of functional components though cuz we lose the extends and type check capability. What is recommended to compensate for that?

Comment: What type check you losing exactly, what do you mean? Losing `extends` is actually good thing because it is extra code that does nothing, it does not bring anything useful. Here is the guide how to use TS with React https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components